# How make Multiple Integrations (twitter + skype) in dialogflow-intégrations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, twitter, dialogflow-es, skype

I use https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations

I managed to get twitter then skype to work but when I change ENV INTEGRATION it's one or the other suddenly how do we make both work, I don't understand.

Comment: If you are using the same repository then you just can configure  the Dockerfile once per path, if you use another repository path for the second integration you can have a diferent Dockerfile and another ENV INTEGRATION configuration and with this an aislolated deployment of each integration, therefor,  are you using the same repository path? or you cloned the repository in another path.

Comment: I added an answer, thanks for seeing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a deployment for each service (twitter, skype) in different directory of a copy of the repository of the same link you tried https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dialogflow-integrations

I copied the repository in a different directory for each service, so I have a directory for twitter and another for skype deployment.

Therefore, I have a Dockerfile in each directory, so I have an ENV INTEGRATION in each directory and I set this environmental variable with the service to deploy, one with twitter and the other with skype.

Directory1/Dockerfile

```
ENV INTEGRATION=twitter
```

Directory2/Dockerfile

```
ENV INTEGRATION=skype
```

You must set the credentials of each service and the GCP project id in the server.js file in the service directory and copy the json key file in the service directory

```
Directory1/twitter/*.json
Directory1/twitter/server.js

Directory2/twitter/*.json
Directory2/twitter/server.js
```

After that configuration, you should deploy each service, so, you should enter to each directory and run the commands in the README.md file to deploy the integration in Cloud Run

```
gcloud builds submit --tag gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/dialogflow-PLATFORM

gcloud beta run deploy --image gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/dialogflow-PLATFORM --update-env-vars GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=YOUR_KEY_FILE --memory 1Gi
```

With this I could deploy both services and have them available at the same time. This is my result of both deployments in Cloud Run. [image: evidence]